# Calculating attrition in SQL

Tags: sql

I am more or less noob to sql so I would really appreciate if anyone of you could give some hints how start to deal with the task below.

We have a database of donatons made by regular donors to an NGO.
Fields: donor_id, date

We need to crate an attrition table listing the donation periods and the proportion of donors who are still donating the organization after n months.

As we count donors from their first donation, the first period is 100%, than the request should check if the donor gave donation in the 2nd, 3rd Nth month after the donors's first donation.

```
Donation    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11

donor 1     1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0 
donor 2     1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   0
donor 3     1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

Any idea? :) Thank you!

PS: until know we used excel or google sheets for this but now we got a databse with 50 million rows, so I have been told to find a solution quickly.

Comment: desired o/p sample will help

Comment: What your output should look like? How long ago the last donation was made, per donor? How about donors that make donations reguarly, but not every month? Etc.

Comment: You might first want to change your schema to do it the relational way and have a table that links one donor with one month of a donation per row instead of your spreadsheet like 13 column one.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I was not clear, the current data is only 2 columns, dodnor_ID, donation_date, the desired format is the 13 column version.